# Undefined index: connection_string

Tags: indexing, undefined, slim

I am trying to install an app and got this message

```
Slim Application Error

The application could not run because of the following error:
Details
Type: ErrorException
Code: 8
Message: Undefined index: connection_string
File: /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/file2/app/config/initializers/setup.php
Line: 198
Trace

#0 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/file2/app/config/initializers/setup.php(198): Slim\Slim::handleErrors(8, 'Undefined index...', '/Applications/M...', 198, Array)
#1 [internal function]: {closure}()
#2 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/file2/app/Slim/Router.php(172): call_user_func_array(Object(Closure), Array)
#3 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/file2/app/Slim/Slim.php(1222): Slim\Router->dispatch(Object(Slim\Route))
#4 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/file2/app/Slim/Middleware/Flash.php(86): Slim\Slim->call()
#5 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/file2/app/Slim/Middleware/MethodOverride.php(94): Slim\Middleware\Flash->call()
#6 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/file2/app/Slim/Middleware/PrettyExceptions.php(67): Slim\Middleware\MethodOverride->call()
#7 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/file2/app/Slim/Slim.php(1174): Slim\Middleware\PrettyExceptions->call()
#8 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/file2/app/config/initializers/setup.php(358): Slim\Slim->run()
#9 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/file2/app/config/boot.php(127): require('/Applications/M...')
#10 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/file2/index.php(7): require('/Applications/M...')
#11 {main}
```

I tried to fix this by changing the error report level in php.ini but got no luck.
it doesn't seem like a problem of the script since many people installed it successfully.

Answer (score 0):

It's the browser thing.
I used the browser that doesn't save cookies.